# Will images not load with the page if the image tags are written with javascript and require user input?

Tags: javascript

I wanted a way to load images only when needed but am hesitant to use AJAX. Instead, will something like this work?

```
<div onclick="loadimages()">Section Title</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
function loadimages()
{
    document.write('<img src="images/thumbnail1.jpg" />');
    document.write('<img src="images/thumbnail2.jpg" />');
    document.write('<img src="images/thumbnail3.jpg" />');
}
</script>
```

The intent is for the images to appear below the "Section Title" when that div is clicked, and for the images to be loaded only at that time.

Comment: For the love of all that is holy, don't use `document.write`. You can add the `<img>` elements to the DOM instead. jQuery makes this stupid simple.

Comment: also consider the Image object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add elements to the DOM dynamically there are several choices *much* more preferable than the abhorrent `document.write`. For example, you can do this:

```
var image = document.createElement("img");
image.src = "images/thumbnail1.jpg";

var parent = document.getElementById("foo"); // identify the parent somehow
parent.appendChild(image);
```

Or you could do this:

```
var parent = document.getElementById("foo"); // identify the parent somehow
parent.innerHTML += '<img src="..." />';
```

Or, if you use jQuery:

```
$("your selector here").append('<img src="..." />');
```

Comment: Thanks, this answers how I add the images. Will this ensure that the browser only loads these images when the javascript runs?

Comment: @Yves: Yes, because it doesn't know anything about them before this code runs. You can also see this for yourself using your browser's developer tools (look at the timeline of network accesses).

Answer (score 1):

Edit: Untested code -- typed on the fly.

`document.write` won't do what you want after the page has loaded, you'd have to do something with the DOM..

Like, perhaps:

```
<div id='section_title' onclick="loadimages()">Section Title</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
function loadimages()
{
    var pics = ['thumbnail1.jpg', 'thumbnail2.jpg', 'thumbnail3.jpg'];
    var i, img, el;
    el = document.getElementById('section_title');
    for (i = 0; i < pics.length; i++) {
      img = document.createElement("img");
      img.src = pics[i];
      el.appendChild(div);
    }
}
</script>
```

Another way would be to put the images in your HTML file, but with `display:none` to hide them and unhide as needed.

Or, depending on the purpose, put them in the HTML as normal, then hide them on load and unhide then when needed.

Answer (score 0):

When you do `document.write('something');`
This `something` will replace entire contents of your `document`.

What you can do is, create new elements dynamically and append them at appropriate places.

Comment: It will certainly not replace the contents of the document.

Comment: I had faced a similar issue sometime ago. `document.write` was making the entire document empty and then add new contents..

Comment: It can do that, but not when it's embedded in the HTML. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.write